# func adder() func(int) int の意味

Tags: go

最後の `int` が返り値の型なのは分かりますが、その前の `func(int)` が分かりません。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```go
func adder() func(int) int {
  ...
}
```

であれば、`adder()`の返す型は`func(int) int`、つまり関数(クロージャ)です。最後の`int`は`adder`ではなく帰ってくるその関数の返す型となるわけです。

https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/25